# Prometheus empty query result when adding metrics

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-node-exporter

I have a strange setup where I need to add together the read rates of a number of the disks in a server.

Each of these queries works fine by itself, but when I add them with a plus sign I get "Empty Query Result"

`irate(node_disk_read_bytes_total{instance="10.0.0.10:9100", device="sdc"}[1m]) + irate(node_disk_read_bytes_total{instance="10.0.0.10:9100", device="sdd"}[1m])`

It may be important to note that I can't just sum all of the devices, I need to add only specific devices.  I'm pretty new to this, but unfortunately, this seems to be one of those things that you can't google properly because of common words.  Or maybe I just don't know the right question to ask.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe the metrics don't line up exactly in time?  I tried this: `avg(metric1)-avg(metric2)` instead of `metric1-metric2` and it seemed to work

Answer (score 1):

Prometheus performs arithmetic operations such as `q1 + q2` in the following way:

1. It executes `q1` and `q2`.
2. It strips metric names from time series results obtained at step 1. E.g. time series results have only labels without metric names after this step.
3. For each time series at the left side of `+` it searches for the corresponding time series at the right side of `+` with the same set of `label="value"` pairs. If it cannot find the matching pair, then the series at the left side is skipped.
4. If the matching series on the right side of `+` is found, then Prometheus sums point values for the series pair individually per each point timestamp.
5. If there are unprocessed series at the left side of `+` exist, then go to 3.
6. Return the resulting series.

See [these docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#arithmetic-binary-operators) for details.

In your case the query returns empty result because series on the left side of `+` contain label `device="sdc"` while series on the right side of `+` contain label `device="sdd"`. This means that Prometheus cannot locate series pairs on the left and the right side of `+` with identical sets of labels. See the step 3 in the algorithm above.

There are the followimg workarounds exist for this issue:

1. To select the needed series with a single [series selector](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#time-series-selectors), and wrap it into `sum()`:

```
sum(
 
 rate(node_disk_read_bytes_total{instance="10.0.0.10:9100", device=~"sdc|sdd"}[1m])
)
```

2. To use `ignoring` modifier with `+` operator in order to instruct Prometgeus to ignore the `device` label during searching for matching series pairs with identical labelsets:

```
rate(node_disk_read_bytes_total{instance="10.0.0.10:9100", device="sdc"}[1m])
  + ignoring(device)
rate(node_disk_read_bytes_total{instance="10.0.0.10:9100", device="sdd"}[1m])
```

See [these docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#vector-matching) for details.

P.s. it isn't recommended to use `irate()` function, since it doesn't capture spikes. It just returns results calculated on a jumpy subset of raw samples, so it may return completely different results on every graph refresh. See [this article](https://valyala.medium.com/why-irate-from-prometheus-doesnt-capture-spikes-45f9896d7832) for details.